# Send JSON data via POST (ajax) and receive json response from Controller (MVC)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, json

I created a function in javascript like that:

```
function addNewManufacturer() {
    var name = $("#id-manuf-name").val();
    var address = $("#id-manuf-address").val();
    var phone = $("#id-manuf-phone").val();
    
    var sendInfo = {
        Name: name,
        Address: address,
        Phone: phone
    };
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Home/Add",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            if (msg) {
                alert("Somebody" + name + " was added in list !");
                location.reload(true);
            } else {
                alert("Cannot add to list !");
            }
        },
        data: sendInfo
    });
}
```

I called `jquery.json-2.3.min.js` script file and I used it for `toJSON(array)` method.

In controller, I have this `Add` action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(PersonSheets sendInfo) {
    bool success = _addSomethingInList.AddNewSomething( sendInfo );

    return this.Json( new {
         msg = success
    });
      
}
```

**But `sendInfo` as method parameter becomes null.**

The model:

```
public struct PersonSheets
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public string Address;
    public string Phone;
}

public class PersonModel
{
    private List<PersonSheets> _list;
    public PersonModel() {
         _list= GetFakeData();
    }

    public bool AddNewSomething(PersonSheets info) {
         if ( (info as object) == null ) {
            throw new ArgumentException( "Person list cannot be empty", "info" );
         }

         PersonSheets item= new PersonSheets();
         item.Id = GetMaximumIdValueFromList( _list) + 1;
         item.Name = info.Name;
         item.Address = info.Address;
         item.Phone = info.Phone;
             
         _list.Add(item);

         return true;
    }
}
```

How could I do in action method when the data was sent with POST ?

I don't know how to use.
Also, it is possible to send back the response (to ajax) via JSON ?

Comment: Hi Snake Eyes. Can you please change the accepted answer to Neha's answer?  The answer by Praveen Prasad is currently broken as it (at time of writing) fails to encode JSON, and fails to set JSON Content-Type header. Neha's correctly does both of these. I've tested both answers.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

### Create a model

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

### Controllers Like Below

```
    public ActionResult PersonTest()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PersonSubmit(Vh.Web.Models.Person person)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);  /*simulating slow connection*/

        /*Do something with object person*/


        return Json(new {msg="Successfully added "+person.Name });
    }
```

### Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function send() {
        var person = {
            name: $("#id-name").val(),
            address:$("#id-address").val(),
            phone:$("#id-phone").val()
        }

        $('#target').html('sending..');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/test/PersonSubmit',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#target').html(data.msg);
            },
            data: JSON.stringify(person)
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: dataType and contentType are important

Answer (score 166):

```
var SendInfo= { SendInfo: [... your elements ...]};

        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'Your-URI',
            data: JSON.stringify(SendInfo),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data) {
                ...
            }
        });
```

and in action

```
public ActionResult AddDomain(IEnumerable<PersonSheets> SendInfo){
...
```

you can bind your array like this

```
var SendInfo = [];

$(this).parents('table').find('input:checked').each(function () {
    var domain = {
        name: $("#id-manuf-name").val(),
        address: $("#id-manuf-address").val(),
        phone: $("#id-manuf-phone").val(),
    }

    SendInfo.push(domain);
});
```

hope this can help you.

Comment: Isn't it so that stringify'ing  the model rises some security concerns as on can tamper the data and insert some XSS vulnerabilities?

Comment: @Dave no, an endpoint (in this case an mvc controller function) should NEVER trust a client, therefore the XSS check should be done at the server. The controller is responsible for parsing the data in the correct way and send the data back to the caller (webapp). The caller could also be something like fiddler, or postman, or maybe another app.. Hope this makes sense..

Comment: FYI, sending a charset with application/json is invalid.  Charset only applies to text/* types.  application/json is ALWAYS UTF-8, regardless of any headers.

Comment: When I replace dataType with contentType in the request, it works.

Comment: My problem solved using JSON.stringify(), can anyone little explain why we need this while if someone sending json object?

Comment: @MohammadZeshan Likely because the body, across the wire, would look like `[object]` instead of your string of values.  You'd be asking the endpoint, which would likely be C#, to read a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 14):

Use `JSON.stringify(<data>)`.

Change your code: `data: sendInfo` to `data: JSON.stringify(sendInfo)`.
Hope this can help you.

Comment: You may need to set the contentType to 'application/json' as well. Some endpoints may guess, but telling them it is JSON is more reliable.

Answer (score 10):

To post JSON, you will need to stringify it. `JSON.stringify` and set the `processData` option to false.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    processData: false,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
    complete: callback
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to use JSON.stringify
And in the Flask use  json.loads

```
res = request.get_data("data")
d_token = json.loads(res)
```

json.loads returns a dictionary, te values can be retrieved d_token['tokenID']

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/subscribe",
            contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({'tokenID':  token}),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
              
            }
     });
```

Flask

```
@app.route('/test', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test():
    res = request.get_data("data")
    d_token = json.loads(res)
    logging.info("Test called..{}".format(d_token["tokenID"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PersonSheets has a property `int Id`, `Id` isn't in the post, so modelbinding fails. Make Id nullable (int?) or send atleast Id = 0 with the POst .

Answer (score 0):

```
    const URL = "http://localhost:8779/api/v1/account/create";
    let reqObj = {accountName:"", phoneNo:""}

    const httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let accountName = document.getElementById("accountName").value
    let phoneNo = document.getElementById("phoneNo").value
    reqObj.accountName = accountName;
    reqObj.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    console.log(reqObj);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(reqObj))
    httpRequest.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById("mylabel").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
    httpRequest.open("POST", URL);
    httpRequest.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    httpRequest.send(reqObj);
```

Answer (score -2):

You don't need to call `$.toJSON` and add `traditional = true`

```
data: { sendInfo: array },
traditional: true
```

would do.

Comment: no good choice ! If I follow your code then the method parameter `Add(object[] sendInfo)` will be null !