# How I would call a C# function from javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to figure out how I would call a C# function from a javascript confirm box.  i.e. If user selects 'OK' a function is called, and if user selects 'Cancel' another function is called.
All the code is located in the back page, and looks as follows:

```
Response.Write(@"
    <script language='javascript'>
    var msg=confirm('Your new document has been created.\nPress OK to go there now, or Cancle to create another document.');
    if (msg==true) {<%=redirect()%>;}
    else {<%=clearForm()%>;}
    </script>
");

protected void redirect(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("myPage.aspx");
}

protected void clearForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //More code here//
}
```

Note that all the code within the Response.Redirect is all on one line, I just split it up here for simplicity!
Anyways, this does not work, and I cant find a solution.  I've tried various different things within the `if` statement

My first idea was not to give the user an option, and to simply use:

```
Response.Write(@"<script language='javascript'>alert('Your new document has been created.');</script>");
Response.Redirect("TaskPanel.aspx");
```

But when I tried this, the page did not wait for the user to click OK before redirecting, and hence made it pointless.

Comment: Send a JSON request to the server to invoke the function. There are several things wrong with your code.

First of all, you're writing javascript as a string which will become increasingly harder for you to maintain.

Second, redirection and clearing the form both can be performed via javascript on the client side.

Comment: use ajax and web service

Comment: For the redirect and the form clear, you do not need to call the code behind, do it with simple javascript.

Comment: I should of also noted that when the user clicks a button on the page, an SqlConnection is made and details inserted into a table, then after the `connection.Close();` comes the code above.  I wasn't sure how else to invoke the JavaScript from the C#.

Comment: For more of an explanation you might review [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11946530/creating-an-xml-file-using-javascript/11946959#11946959)

Answer (score 3):

You are getting confused between server-side and client-side code.  The C# code you posed will run on your server and write out the JavaScript code on the page:

```
<script language='javascript'>
    var msg=confirm('Your new document has been created.\nPress OK to go there now, or Cancle to create another document.');
    if (msg==true) {<%=redirect()%>;}
    else {<%=clearForm()%>;}
</script>
```

The JavaScript you write out will be run on the client-side browswer.

However, I would imagine you will get a JavaScript error, since it will attempt to write out `<%=redirect()%>;` and `<%=clearForm()%>;` which is ASPX scriptlet code that should have been run on the server-side (but is actually appearing as a String in the JavaScript on the client).

This is just an explanation/answer to why you cannot call a C# function directly from JavaScript.

For your specific problem, you do not need to call back to the server to do a redirect or clear form.

Both of these can be done in JavaScript.

The redirect can be done with JavaScript `window.location="myPage.aspx"` or `self.location="myPage.aspx"`

The clear form can be done with JavaScript  `form.reset()`

Answer (score 1):

Yes its simple just : put you callback function in a file

After that you should bind click on **OK** you call the function with : **AJAX** 
with any javascript Framework to make simple

OK
Cancel

```
$("#OK,#Cancel").click(function(){

 var whichFct = $(this).attr('fct');      var urlToFile = "web/app/link/fct/1";
 if(whichFct == 2)  urlToFile = "web/app/link/fct/2"

   $.post(urlToFile,function() {
            //do sthlike hiding the form ...
       });
});
```

Its just simple than this

Answer (score 0):

pass a javascript function on buttonclick.. then write following code in .aspx page:

```
<script language='javascript'>
function func_name()
{
var msg=confirm('Your new document has been created.\nPress OK to go there now, or Cancle to create another document.')
if (msg==true) {<%=redirect()%>}
else {<%=clearForm()%>}
}
</script>
```

do similarly for other button as well.