# How do I use ajax with mvc4 without a service?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm pretty new to MVC and I'm just thinking ahead to my next project. I haven't been able to find any examples of how to do this, so I apologize if it seems like a question that may have already been answered somewhere else.

I'm going to want to create asynchronous cascading dropdown menus. So menu B will update as the values in menu A change, and menu C will update as either A or B update. What is the normal pattern for this?

Normally, as list events fire, I would use ajax to call a service that would process my input data and return json which I would use to update my lists. In this case, there is no service, only the controller feeding the view. We could create a service, but we prefer not to if at all possible. So I'm wondering if there is a technique in MVC4 that can feed me back what I need to update the view without re-rendering the page.

If someone could refer me to an example or at least explain what I might be looking for, that would be a great help. TIA

Comment: I'm confused as to your question. What do you mean by a service? A service layer? Why can't the view / ajax talk to controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the Ajax callback URL as a controller action (in fact, that is how I typically do it).

There is no need for a separate service.

```
public class CallbackController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MenuOptions()
    {
        // return e.g. JSON 
    }
}
```

The Ajax URL would be

http://myserver.com/Callback/MenuOptions

Comment: Well hell. I guess I didn't realize ActionResult was so general. thanks

Comment: Yep.  If you're returning JSON, look at JsonResult: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.108).aspx

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of answers around the web for this type of functionality. [Here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227624/asp-net-mvc-controller-actions-that-return-json-or-partial-html), [and here is another similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517071/send-json-data-via-post-ajax-and-receive-json-response-from-controller-mvc). What you should really do is read up on [MVC actions / controllers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/getting-started-with-mvc/getting-started-with-mvc-part1) and do some spiking / messing around.

Building the example starter app will help you get a grasp on the differences between classic ASP.NET and MVC.