# Slow Form Processing in PHP - Need Queue?

Tags: php, mysql, validation, queue, gearman

I have a web form which I want to validate the inputs, and if it passes validation, send the info to a web service, and save to mySQL as a backup. If there is an error either sending to the web service, or with sql, I want to email myself an alert to let me know. When there are no errors, everything runs fine. To test what would happen if there is an error, I have put in the wrong mysql credentials. When this happens, the whole script takes about 30 seconds to process. I'm wondering if there is a way to run the validation part and return the response, before finishing the script. I want to call the web service and save to mysql in the background, after the response to the server has been sent. Is this possible? Would I need to implement something like gearman?

Also, this would be a fairly high volume form. If two people tried to submit at the same time, would there be a mysql issue? Are there any ways to better improve security? I'm a beginner so any extra advice would be great.

Thanks!

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST) ){
//form validation vars
$formok = true;
$errors = array();

//sumbission data
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

//
//form data
//

//Services
if(isset($_POST['services'])) {     
    $services = $_POST['services'];
} else {
    $services = array(
        'Neck' => NULL,
        'Back' => NULL,
        'Other' => NULL,
    );
}

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];   
$lastname = $_POST['lastname']; 
$email = $_POST['email'];

$telephone = $_POST['telephone'];
$TelephoneSanitized = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $telephone); //format phone as number only

//if phone number does not start with 1, and the length is less than 11 characters, add the 1 to the beginning
if ((substr($TelephoneSanitized, 0, 1) != '1') && (strlen($TelephoneSanitized) < 11)) {
    $TelephoneSanitized = "1".$TelephoneSanitized;      
     }

//$state = strip_tags($_POST['state']);
$location = $_POST['location'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$leadsource = $_POST['leadsource']; 
$refId = $_POST['refId'];   
$isconsult = $_POST['isconsult'];

//Third Party Emails
if(isset($_POST['receiveThirdPtyEmails'])) {        
    $receiveThirdPtyEmails = strip_tags($_POST['receiveThirdPtyEmails']);
} else {
    $receiveThirdPtyEmails = NULL;      
}

//
//validation
//  

//validate location has been set
if($location == 0){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "Please select your nearest location";
}

//validate name is not empty
if(empty($firstname)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "Please enter your first name";
}
if(empty($lastname)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "Please enter your last name";
}

//validate email address is not empty
if(empty($email)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "Please enter your email address";
//validate email address is valid
}elseif(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "You have not entered a valid email address";
}

//validate phone is not empty
if(empty($telephone)){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "Please enter your phone number";
}
//validate phone is at least 10 characters
elseif(strlen($TelephoneSanitized) < 10){
    $formok = false;
    $errors[] = "Your phone number must be at least 10 characters";
}

//what we need to return back to our form
$returndata = array(
    'posted_form_data' => array(
        'services' => $services,
        'firstname' => $firstname,
        'lastname' => $lastname,
        'email' => $email,
        'telephone' => $telephone,
        //'state' => $state,
        'location' => $location,
        'message' => $message
    ),
    'form_ok' => $formok,
    'errors' => $errors,
);

//if this is not an ajax request  
if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) !== 'xmlhttprequest'){  

    //set session variables  
    session_start();  
    $_SESSION['cf_returndata'] = $returndata;  

    //redirect back to form  
    header('location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);  

}
//
//send to web service if all is ok
//
if($formok){

    //build query string
    $fields = array('services' => $services,
            'location' => $location,
            'firstname' => $firstname,
            'lastname' => $lastname,
            'email' => $email,
            'emailconfirm' => $email,
            'phone' => $TelephoneSanitized,
            'comments' => $message,
            'refid' => $refId,
            'leadsource' => $leadsource,
            'isconsult' => $isconsult,
            'receiveThirdPtyEmails' => $receiveThirdPtyEmails);

    $url = "http://fake.aspx?" . http_build_query($fields, '', "&");

    $url = preg_replace('/%5B[a-zA-Z]+%5D/', '', $url);

    $curl_handle = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $results = curl_exec($curl_handle);
    curl_close($curl_handle);

}

//
//save data to mysql if all is ok PDO
//
if($formok){

    // Connecting to the MySQL server
    $host="fakehost-on the same server as form";
    $user_name="fakeuser";
    $pwd="fakepass";
    $database_name="fakedb";        

    $services = implode(',',array_filter($services)); // change array to string

    date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
    $date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($date));

    // mysql
    try {  
        //connect to db  
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database_name", $user_name, $pwd);
        //set error handling
        $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        //prepare statement
        $q = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO leads 
        (ip_address, lead_time, location, first_name, last_name, email_address, telephone, comments, services, receiveThirdPtyEmails, leadsource, refid) 
        VALUES 
        (:ip_address, :lead_time, :location, :first_name, :last_name, :email_address, :telephone, :comments, :services, :receiveThirdPtyEmails, :leadsource, :refid)");

        //execute statement                 
        $q->execute(array(
            ':ip_address'=>$ipaddress,
            ':lead_time'=>$date,
            ':location'=>$location,
            ':first_name'=>$firstname,
            ':last_name'=>$lastname,
            ':email_address'=>$email,
            ':telephone'=>$TelephoneSanitized,
            ':comments'=>$message,
            ':services'=>$services,
            ':receiveThirdPtyEmails'=>$receiveThirdPtyEmails,
            ':leadsource'=>$leadsource,
            ':refid'=>$refId));

    }  
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        $error_code = $e->getMessage();      // Specify the error code 
        $error_type = "SQL Insert Failed";
        require_once("resources/error-mailer.php");   // Include the error mailer script  
    }  
    # close the connection  
    $conn = null;       
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript/jQuery using JSON and AJAX is your best bet. There's a great example here:

[Send JSON data via POST (ajax) and receive json response from Controller (MVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517071/send-json-data-via-post-ajax-and-receive-json-response-from-controller-mvc)

Also security wise, you'll want to use the mysqli_real_escape_string():

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

on strings values you accept via POST or GET before you put the value into your query. It avoids SQL injection. For integers use abs(intval($_POST['posted_integer'])) or ctype_digit, whatever floats your needs, or preg_replace() / preg_match() regular expressions.

DO NOT let POST or GET values go untouched into your database!!

Comment: I will be submitting with Jquery/Ajax, but I do want the form to be accessible with JS turned off. Since I'm using PDO and not mySQLi, doesn't PDO do the escaping automatically?

Comment: It will do the escaping as in add the ticks ` to your table names, not stop someone from passing a SELECT/UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE as a subquery.