# Send JS object to C# Controller using Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax

I am trying to send multiple objects in js to a controller in C# using an Ajax call.

I have a object in C# called "Person"

which is the next :

```
public class Person
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

and I have the same object In JavaScript.

Then create two persons and I send to the controller.
This is the Ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    url: baseUrl + "/controller/TestPeople",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        people: people
    },
    success: function (resp) {
        alert("ok");
    }
});
```

This is the post

```
people[0][Title]:"Mr."
people[0][FirstName]:"fname1"
people[0][LastName]:"Lname1"
people[0][Age]:23
people[1][Title]:"Mr."
people[1][FirstName]:"fname2"
people[1][LastName]:"Lname2"
people[1][Age]:25
```

but when i receive it in the controller, everything is null

```
public string TestPeople(Person[] people){
   //some code
}
```

the controller knows that there are 2 people but all the information inside is null.

Any idea why?

To "solve" the problem i change the controller to use `FormCollection` and it is working, but i would like to know why the other is not working.

Thanks for all.

Comment: Try `data: people` instead of `data: { people: people }`.

Comment: hi @haim770 this is the small example, i use this because i send more than one object, all of them have the same problem

Comment: @TiGreX try this `public string TestPeople([FromBody] Person[] people)`

Comment: @Nasreddine , I still having the same result.

Comment: Can you show us some actual code on the receiving end? Is this a webapi or MVC controller?

Comment: @Nasreddine I only have this there and a return "test", and is an MVC controller

Comment: Have you tried setting dataType: json in $.ajax?

Comment: @NEDian yes, same result, everything null

Comment: @TiGreX Can you show how JSON you are sending looks like?

Comment: Please try this  **IEnumuarable<Person> people** or  **List<Person> people**

Comment: @NEDian @Kamo for the json, this time i added this `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` and `data: JSON.stringify(object), `now works fine. thanks for all. I followed this post here (the second answer) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517071/send-json-data-via-post-ajax-and-receive-json-response-from-controller-mvc thanks for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
data : JSON.stringify(peopleArray)
```

In your controller try:

```
public string Get(Person[] people){
   //some code
}
```