# How do I get pass a populated custom class from javascript through AJAX to .NET MVC app?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following .net class in c#:

```
public class BusinessModel
{
    public string BlobName { get; set; }
    public string NewName { get; set; }
}
```

And I have the following action in my MVC Ajax Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DoBusiness(string handle, BusinessModel businessData)
{
    // Do stuff with the business data.
}
```

First I try to use the following Javascript code to invoke this:

```
var bd = JSON.stringify({ BlobName: "blob", NewName: "new" });

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Ajax/DoBusiness",
    data: { handle: "MyHandle", businessData: bd },
    success: businessComplete,
    error: businessFailed
});
```

And in this case, using fiddler to view, the following is how the data is rendered on the request:

> handle=MyHandle&businessData=%7B%22BlobName%22%3A%22blob%22%2C%22NewName%22%3A%22new%22%7D

Which is the following decoded:

> handle=MyHandle&businessData={"BlobName":"blob","NewName":"new"}

But when I use the Visual Studio debugger to look at the values actually passed to the controller action, the value of the parameter "handle" is "MyHandle" as expected, but the value of the parameter "businessData" is null.

Now I alter the Javascript code to read as follows (merely removing the JSON.stringify call):

```
var bd = { BlobName: "blob", NewName: "new" };

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Ajax/DoBusiness",
    data: { handle: "MyHandle", businessData: bd },
    success: businessComplete,
    error: businessFailed
});
```

In this case, the data (shown by fiddler) is rendered in the request as:

> handle=MyHandle&businessData%5BBlobName%5D=blob&businessData%5BNewName%5D=new

Which is the following decoded:

> handle=MyHandle&businessData[BlobName]=blob&businessData[NewName]=new

And in this case, the Visual Studio debugger still shows that "handle" is set to "MyHandle" as expected, but instead of being null, the "businessData" parameter is filled with an actual instance, but both properties "BlobName" and "NewName" are set to null.

**Finally the question:** What am I doing wrong?  How can I actually get that class properly populated in the controller action?

**EDIT In response to comment on possible duplicate:**
The possible duplicate, titled "Send JSON data via POST (ajax) and receive json response from Controller (MVC)" specifically addresses how to send instances of models bound with MVC binding.  My question is more not related to an object that might be MVC-bound.  I am curious about how to populate ANY object, that might be arbitrarily provided.

**EDIT In response to Stephen's comment:**
This is a simplified scenario.  The real-life actual use-case has an overlapping set of Ajax calls, and this one is called in response to a previous one which has passed along an arbitrary object constructed on the server which it wants back in the subsequent call (this example).  Providing that fully-fleshed real-life use case would, in my opinion, make this question unduly long, so pardon the simplification, and I hope this explanation will serve to appropriately frame the context.

Comment: `data: { handle: "MyHandle", BlobName: "blob", NewName: "new" },`

Comment: Well thanks, but I need a generalized solution.  This is a simplified model for the purposes of this question.... I would like to know how to pass custom classes properly.

Comment: You pass the custom class by passing the name/value pairs of its properties (as I showed)

Comment: Thanks, but in the actual use case, I am getting an object in response to a previous ajax call that the server is expecting to get back as a single bundle called "businessData".  Although my example in this question shows me constructing from whole cloth in Javascript, that isn't the actual source in real life.  In real life, Javascript merely has an object that it knows it wants to ship up to the server, and it knows the server should understand it because it was provided by the server in the first place.

Comment: Then show your real case!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send JSON data via POST (ajax) and receive json response from Controller (MVC)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517071/send-json-data-via-post-ajax-and-receive-json-response-from-controller-mvc)

Comment: Your still not telling us what the real use case is. Best guess is that your first ajax call is returning a `BusinessModel` model object, and assuming you have assigned it to `var bd`, then you can just add additional properties - `db.handle = 'MyHandle';` and then post back the model and the value of `handle` using `data: db;`

Comment: Well, this is a good solution and it works for me right now.  If you had posted as the answer, I would have marked it as such.

So Thank you!

There is a longer term issue in that in the future, we will want to be providing more than a single instance in the same ajax call, and heeded by the same controller action.  So the problem will re-arise, I believe.  As those classes could have properties with the same name, we could be back in the same soup.  But for now I'm off and running.  THANKS.

Answer (score 0):

Please see Stephan Muecke's comment.  He provided the answer that works at least for now.