# Paging .net MVC - without download all records from WebService

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, pagination

I have a following problem. I want to do nice paging and I do not want to download all records from WebService to my application.

Controller code:

```
public ActionResult Vacations(int? page)
        {
            int pageNumber = page ?? 1;
            int quantity = 5;
            using (MyWebService.MyWebServiceClient client = new MyWebService.MyWebServiceClient())
            {
                var vacations = client.GetUserAbsence(SessionManager.CurrentToken, quantity, pageNumber); 
                var onePageOfVacations = vacations.ToPagedList(pageNumber, quantity);
                ViewBag.OnePageOfVacations = onePageOfVacations;
            }
            return View();
        }
```

View Code:

```
<h2>Vacations</h2>
<div>
    <table class="table tablesorter table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Data od</th>
                <th>Data do</th>
                <th>Ilość dni</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @{
                foreach (var v in ViewBag.OnePageOfVacations)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@v.From_Date</td>
                        <td>@v.To_Date</td>
                        <td>@v.Element_Name</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Data od</th>
                <th>Data do</th>
                <th>Ilość dni</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</div>

<!-- output a paging control that lets the user navigation to the previous page, next page, etc -->
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.OnePageOfVacations, page => Url.Action("Vacations", new { page }))
```

I have a method in my webservice "GetUserAbsence()" which return to my only that number of records which I need. Now I have only one page and I cannot show other results. There is my question - how to connect this solution with PagedList or maybe how to create new paging on this solution?

Comment: You'll need to use ajax or something similar otherwise the view can't get updated, it's totally static and can't call back to the server and tell it to send more data. I don't have much time to send you more info but this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517071/send-json-data-via-post-ajax-and-receive-json-response-from-controller-mvc

Comment: If you know the total number of records, you can use `StaticPagedList`, for example, `ViewBag.OnePageOfVacations = new StaticPagedList<yourModel>(vacations, pageNumber, quantity, totalItems);` (may mean you need a 2nd service method that returns `.Count()` but that should be very fast (alternatively you could modify the method to return an object containing the records and the count)

Comment: Please make from comment an answer. Thanks Stephen! It Works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MVC.PagedList has a `StaticPagedList` method that allow you to provide `IEnumerable<T>` rather than `IQuerable<T>`, but you must know the total number of records. In your case it would be

```
var vacations = client.GetUserAbsence(SessionManager.CurrentToken, quantity, pageNumber);
int totalItems = .... // see following note
ViewBag.OnePageOfVacations = new StaticPagedList<yourModel>(vacations, pageNumber, quantity, totalItems);
```

It means that your service would need to include another method that returns the count of total records (but that should be very fast), or you could modify the `GetUserAbsence()` method to return an object containing properties for the filtered collection plus a value for the total records.

Side note: I recommend that you pass a strongly typed model to the view rather that using `ViewBag`, so that the controller code is

```
....
var model = new StaticPagedList<yourModel>(vacations, pageNumber, quantity, totalItems);
return View(model);
```

and in the view

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<yourModel>
....
@foreach (var v in Model)
{
    ....
}
....
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Vacations", new { page }))
```