# How do I make a real pagination using PagedList?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I have one table on database with 10.000 records and I wanna paginate it using PagedList. The problem is that all records are loaded and after that the PagedList paginate them, it is become very slow. I want to make a real paginate for example returning each 20 records till 10.000 and showing them on view, but I cannot make it.

How could I do this ? Any example ?

**Model Search**

```
public class SearchUsuario
{
    public IPagedList<ViewUsuario> lista { get; set; }
    public SearchUsuario(){
        lista = new List<ViewUsuario>().ToPagedList(1, 50);
    }
}
```

**Model ViewUsuario**

```
public class ViewUsuario
{
    public String nome { get; set; }
}
```

**Generic DAO**

```
//returns all records
public IQueryable<T> GetAll()
{
    IQueryable<T> query = context.Set<T>();
    return query;
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult view(int? page)
{
    int pageNumber = page ?? 1;
    int pageSize = 10;
    SearchUsuario search = new SearchUsuario();
    IQueryable<Usuario> lista = new UsuarioDAO().GetAll(); //returns all records
    List<ViewUsuario> listaModel = new List<ViewUsuario>();
    foreach(Usuario u in lista){
        Debug.WriteLine(u.nome);
        ViewUsuario view = new ViewUsuario();
        view.nome = u.nome;
        listaModel.Add(view);
    }
    search.lista = listaModel.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
    return View(search);
}
```

**View**

```
@using PagedList.Mvc
@model SearchUsuario
....   
<table id="grid" class="table table-striped table-hover" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>  
        @foreach (ViewUsuario m in Model.lista){
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(i => m.nome)</td>
            </tr>
        }                         
    </tbody>
</table>
....
Pagina @Model.lista.PageNumber de @Model.lista.PageCount
@Html.PagedListPager(Model.lista, page => Url.Action("view", new{ page = page }))
```

Comment: You need to adjust your db query to `.Skip()` and `.Take()`. You would calculate the pagination values based on the page number and page size.

Comment: See here for an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380413/paging-with-linq-for-objects

Comment: i think your problem is in your `new UsuarioDAO().GetAll()` sentence: you need to return an `IQueryable` not a a materialized collection (like `List` or `Array`) if you use an IQueryable, you can narrow the search to only the items required in the page with the `ToPagedList`, so it would be helpful if you post the code of that class

Comment: @Jasen using as your link suggestion it works, but on `View` doesn't display the index of pages. for example: page 2, page 3, page 4...etc. I need to have 2 Lists or maybe a Count with numbers of records to create this ?

Comment: @xavvvier `UsuarioDAO.GetAll()` returns a IQueryable, see this: ` public IQueryable<T> GetAll(){
        IQueryable<T> query = context.Set<T>();
        return query;
    }`

Comment: Have you checked the generated html to verify that the index links are missing?

Comment: `PagedList` already uses `.Skip()` and `.Take()` internally to perform server side paging. But its designed to work with a `IQueryable` data model. If you have a need to create a view model (which does not seem necessary in your case), then look at using `StaticPagedList`

Comment: @StephenMuecke do you have any example about how to use `StaticPagedList` ?

Comment: Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38373353/paging-net-mvc-without-download-all-records-from-webservice/38374805#38374805) for an example of where it might be relevant. But in you case, there seems no need to a view model and all you need is `IQueryable<Usuario> lista = new UsuarioDAO().GetAll().OrderBy(u => u.nome); search.lista = lista.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);` (and change the property to `public IPagedList<Usuario> lista { get; set; }`

Comment: I rolled back part of your last edit (where you added `.Skip()` and `.Take()` to the query based on comments because it then means you question makes no sense - it would not be 'slow' (but it would mean that you do not get page numbers in the view). I'll add an answer explaining the issue and solution a little later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.ToPagedList()` method internally calls `.Skip()` and `.Take()` to limit the result set to the specified number of records. However it is designed to to take an `IQueryable<T>` of your data model, and is not designed for view models.

Your issue is that your taking your `IQueryable<Usuario>` and using a loop to generate a view model for every record in the database, so not only are you downloading 10,000 records to memory, your also creating 10,000 view models in memory (and then you throw away 9,990 of them)

Based on the code you have shown, you do not need a view model. Instead you can simply use

```
public ActionResult view(int? page)
{
    int pageNumber = page ?? 1;
    int pageSize = 10;
    IQueryable<Usuario> lista = new UsuarioDAO().GetAll();
    SearchUsuario search = new SearchUsuario
    {
        lista = lista.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
    };
    return View(search);
}
```

and change the property in `SearchUsuario` to

```
public IPagedList<Usuario> lista { get; set; }
```

The `ToPagedList()` method will now only download the 10 records you want in the view.

For cases where you do need a view model, then you need to use the `StaticPagedList` method and pass it the total number of records in order for the page number buttons in the view to be rendered correctly. It means a 2nd database call to get the `.Count()` of the records, but that is generally very fast

```
public ActionResult view(int? page)
{
    int pageNumber = page ?? 1;
    int pageSize = 10;
    // Get the count of all records
    int totalRecords = IQueryable<Usuario> lista = new UsuarioDAO().GetAll().Count();
    // Get just the records to be displayed using .Skip() and .Take()
    // and project into your view model
    IEnumerable<ViewUsuario> lista = new UsuarioDAO().GetAll()
        .OrderBy(u => u.nome).Skip(pageSize * pageNumber).Take(pageSize)
        .Select(x => new ViewUsuario
        {
            nome = x.nome,
            ....
        });
    SearchUsuario search = new SearchUsuario
    {
        lista = new StaticPagedList<ViewUsuario>(lista, pageNumber, pageSize, totalRecords);
    }
    return View(search);
}
```

Comment: I need to change something on HTML ?

Comment: Your view code looks fine. What problem are you having?