# Codeigniter - JSON Categories

Tags: javascript, php, json, codeigniter

I want to show Package Categories with JSON. I have 2 Tables. First one is Package Table, second one is packageService. First table is Package Table. I get all data from Package Table. Each Package has own features(services). I show this features Package below on Package View. I want to get all features(services) from packageServices. But I want to get this features by packageServiceId from packageService table with JSON such as [1][2] etc. In Package Table has a column as packageService equal packageServiceId on packageService Table. How can I write data from post form on Edit Page to Package Table with JSON?

Controller of Package:

```
    <?php
    defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Package extends CI_Controller {

        public function __construct()

        {

            parent::__construct();

            $this->load->model('service_model');

        }

        public function index()
        {

            $this->lang->load('content', $this->session->userdata('userLang'));

            //$viewData['packs'] = $this->db->get("package")->result();

            $this->db->order_by('packageId','DESC');
            $viewData['packs_P'] = $this->db->get_where('package',array('packageNameEn'=> 'Platinum'),1)->result();

            $this->db->order_by('packageId','DESC');
            $viewData['packs_S'] = $this->db->get_where('package',array('packageNameEn'=> 'Silver'),1)->result();

            $this->db->order_by('packageId','DESC');
            $viewData['packs_G'] = $this->db->get_where('package',array('packageNameEn'=> 'Gold'),1)->result();

            $this->db->order_by('packageId','DESC');
            $package_n = $this->input->post('packageNameEn');
            $viewData['packs'] = $this->db->get_where('package',array('packageNameEn'=> $package_n),1)->result();

            $this->load->view('package', $viewData);
        }

        public function edit($packageId)
        {

            $this->lang->load('content', $this->session->userdata('userLang'));

            $viewData['packages'] = $this->db->where("packageId", $packageId)->get("package")->result();

            $viewData['packs'] = $this->db->get("package")->result();

            $this->load->view('package_edit', $viewData);
        }

        public function update($packageId) {



            $this->lang->load('content', $this->session->userdata('people_lang'));

            $data = array (

                "packageEditUser" => $this->input->post("packageEditUser"),

                "packageRev" => $packageId,

                "packageNameEn" => $this->input->post("packageNameEn"),

                "packagePrice" => $this->input->post("packagePrice"),

                "packagePriceCut" => $this->input->post("packagePriceCut"),

                "packageActive" => $this->input->post("packageActive"),

                "packageEditDate" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),

            );

            $update = $this->db->insert("package", $data);

            $viewData['services'] = $this->service_model->update_services($packageId);

            $this->load->view('package',$viewData);

            if($update) {

                redirect(base_url("package"));

            }else {

                echo "Hata!";

            }

        }


            public function add()
        {

            $this->lang->load('content', $this->session->userdata('userLang'));

            $viewData['packages'] = $this->db->get("package")->result();

            $this->load->view('package_add', $viewData);
        }

        public function insert() {



            $this->lang->load('content', $this->session->userdata('people_lang'));

            $this->load->view('package');

            $data = array (

                "packageAddUser" => $this->input->post("packageAddUser"),

                "packageNameEn" => $this->input->post("packageNameEn"),

                "packagePrice" => $this->input->post("packagePrice"),

                "packagePriceCut" => $this->input->post("packagePriceCut"),

                "packageActive" => $this->input->post("packageActive"),

                "packageAddDate" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),

                "packageEditDate" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),

                "packageRev" => '0'

            );

            $insert = $this->db->insert("package", $data);

            if($insert) {

                redirect(base_url("package"));

            }else {

                echo "Hata!";

            }

        }



    }
    ?>
```

Package View:

```
<section id="main-content">
    <section class="wrapper site-min-height">
        <!-- page start-->
        <div class="row">
            <!--price start-->
            <div class="text-center feature-head">
                <h1> PACKAGES </h1>
                <p>Choose Your Special Package Plan. </p>
            </div>
            <?php foreach($packs_S as $get) { ?>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
                <div class="pricing-table <?php if ($get->packageNameEn == 'Platinum') { echo 'most-popular'; } ?>">
                    <div class="pricing-head">
                        <h1> <?php echo $get->packageNameEn; ?> </h1>
                        <h5><del>€ <?php echo $get->packagePrice ?></del></h5>
                        <h2><span class="note">€</span><?php echo $get->packagePriceCut ?> </h2>

                    </div>
//json data will write here:
                    <ul class="list-unstyled">
                        <li>8 hours coverage</li>
                        <li>500 digital images</li>
                        <li>100 A3 Hard Copy</li>
                        <li>Bridal portrait with 11X14</li>
                        <li>Engagement portrait with 11X14</li>
                        <li>Income Tax included</li>
                    </ul>
//json data will write here/

                    <div class="price-actions">
                        <a class="btn" href="javascript:;">Get Now</a>
                        <a class="btn" href="<?php echo base_url("package/edit/$get->packageId"); ?>">Edit</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php foreach($packs_G as $get) { ?>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
                    <div class="pricing-table <?php if ($get->packageNameEn == 'Platinum') { echo 'most-popular'; } ?>">
                        <div class="pricing-head">
                            <h1> <?php echo $get->packageNameEn; ?> </h1>
                            <h5><del>€ <?php echo $get->packagePrice ?></del></h5>
                            <h2><span class="note">€</span><?php echo $get->packagePriceCut ?> </h2>

                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li>8 hours coverage</li>
                            <li>500 digital images</li>
                            <li>100 A3 Hard Copy</li>
                            <li>Bridal portrait with 11X14</li>
                            <li>Engagement portrait with 11X14</li>
                            <li>Income Tax included</li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="price-actions">
                            <a class="btn" href="javascript:;">Get Now</a>
                            <a class="btn" href="<?php echo base_url("package/edit/$get->packageId"); ?>">Edit</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php foreach($packs_P as $get) { ?>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
                    <div class="pricing-table <?php if ($get->packageNameEn == 'Platinum') { echo 'most-popular'; } ?>">
                        <div class="pricing-head">
                            <h1> <?php echo $get->packageNameEn; ?> </h1>
                            <h5><del>€ <?php echo $get->packagePrice ?></del></h5>
                            <h2><span class="note">€</span><?php echo $get->packagePriceCut ?> </h2>

                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li>8 hours coverage</li>
                            <li>500 digital images</li>
                            <li>100 A3 Hard Copy</li>
                            <li>Bridal portrait with 11X14</li>
                            <li>Engagement portrait with 11X14</li>
                            <li>Income Tax included</li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="price-actions">
                            <a class="btn" href="javascript:;">Get Now</a>
                            <a class="btn" href="<?php echo base_url("package/edit/$get->packageId"); ?>">Edit</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php foreach($packs as $get) { ?>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-3">
                    <div class="pricing-table <?php if ($get->packageNameEn == 'Platinum') { echo 'most-popular'; } ?>">
                        <div class="pricing-head">
                            <h1> <?php echo $get->packageNameEn; ?> </h1>
                            <h5><del>€ <?php echo $get->packagePrice ?></del></h5>
                            <h2><span class="note">€</span><?php echo $get->packagePriceCut ?> </h2>

                        </div>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li>8 hours coverage</li>
                            <li>500 digital images</li>
                            <li>100 A3 Hard Copy</li>
                            <li>Bridal portrait with 11X14</li>
                            <li>Engagement portrait with 11X14</li>
                            <li>Income Tax included</li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="price-actions">
                            <a class="btn" href="javascript:;">Get Now</a>
                            <a class="btn" href="<?php echo base_url("package/edit/$get->packageId"); ?>">Edit</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
        <!-- page end-->
    </section>
</section>
<!--main content end-->
```

Package Edit View:

```
<form class="cmxform form-horizontal tasi-form" id="signupForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url("package/update/$get->packageId"); ?>">

                            <?php } ?>

                            <!-- Hidden Classes -->

                            <div class="form-group" hidden>

                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">The User Who Edit</label>

                                <div class="col-sm-10">

                                    <input type="text" name="packageEditUser" class="form-control" value="<?php  echo $this->session->userdata('people_id'); ?>" readonly>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group" hidden>

                                <label class="col-sm-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Rev Id</label>

                                <div class="col-sm-10">

                                    <?php foreach($packages as $get) { ?>

                                    <input type="text" name="packageRev" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $get->packageId; ?>" readonly>

                                    <?php } ?>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <!-- / Hidden Classes -->



                            <div class="form-group ">

                                <label for="username" class="control-label col-lg-2">Package Name: </label>

                                <div class="col-lg-10">

                                    <?php foreach($packages as $get) { ?>

                                        <input class=" form-control" type="text" value="<?php echo $get->packageNameEn; ?>" readonly />

                                    <?php } ?>

                                </div>

                            </div>





                            <!-- Basic select -->

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label class="control-label col-lg-3">Package Name <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>

                                <div class="col-lg-9">

                                    <?php foreach($packages as $get) { ?>

                                        <input type="text" name="packageNameEn" class="form-control" placeholder="Package Name" value="<?php echo $get->packageNameEn; ?>">

                                    <?php }?>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <!-- /basic select -->

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label col-lg-2" for="inputSuccess">Services:</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-6">
                                    <div class="checkboxes">
                                        <label class="label_check" for="checkbox-01">
                                            <input name="sample-checkbox-01" id="checkbox-01" value="1" type="checkbox" /> I agree to the terms &#38; conditions.
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="label_check" for="checkbox-02">
                                            <input name="sample-checkbox-02" id="checkbox-02" value="1" type="checkbox" /> Please send me regular updates. </label>
                                        <label class="label_check" for="checkbox-03">
                                            <input name="sample-checkbox-02" id="checkbox-03" value="1" type="checkbox" /> This is nice checkbox.</label>
                                        <label class="label_check" for="checkbox-04">
                                            <input name="sample-checkbox-04" id="checkbox-04" value="1" type="checkbox" /> I agree to the terms &#38; conditions.
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="label_check" for="checkbox-05">
                                            <input name="sample-checkbox-05" id="checkbox-05" value="1" type="checkbox" /> Please send me regular updates. </label>
                                        <label class="label_check" for="checkbox-06">
                                            <input name="sample-checkbox-06" id="checkbox-06" value="1" type="checkbox" /> This is nice checkbox.</label>
                                        <label class="label_check" for="checkbox-07">
                                            <input name="sample-checkbox-07" id="checkbox-07" value="1" type="checkbox" /> I agree to the terms &#38; conditions.
                                        </label>
                                        <label class="label_check" for="checkbox-08">
                                            <input name="sample-checkbox-08" id="checkbox-08" value="1" type="checkbox" /> Please send me regular updates. </label>
                                        <label class="label_check" for="checkbox-09">
                                            <input name="sample-checkbox-09" id="checkbox-09" value="1" type="checkbox" /> This is nice checkbox.</label>
                                        <label class="label_check" for="checkbox-10">
                                            <input name="sample-checkbox-10" id="checkbox-10" value="1" type="checkbox" /> This is nice checkbox.</label>

                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <div class="col-lg-6">

                                    <h5>Package Price:</h5>

                                    <div class="input-group m-bot15">

                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fas fa-euro"></i></span>

                                        <?php foreach($packages as $get) { ?>

                                            <input type="text" name="packagePrice" data-mask="€ 999.99" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $get->packagePrice; ?>">

                                        <?php }?>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                                <div class="col-lg-6">

                                    <h5>Discounted Price:</h5>

                                    <div class="input-group m-bot15">

                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fas fa-euro"></i></span>

                                        <?php foreach($packages as $get) { ?>

                                            <input type="text" name="packagePriceCut" data-mask="€ 999.99" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $get->packagePriceCut; ?>">

                                        <?php }?>

                                    </div>

                                </div>

                            </div>



                            <!-- Basic select -->

                            <div class="form-group">

                                <label class="control-label col-lg-3">Status <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>

                                <div class="col-lg-9">

                                    <select name="packageActive" class="form-control">

                                        <?php foreach($packages as $get) { ?>

                                            <option value="<?php echo $get->packageActive; ?>" readonly><?php if($get->packageActive == 1) {echo 'Active';} else {echo 'Deactive';} ?></option>

                                        <?php }?>

                                        <option value="1">Active</option>

                                        <option value="2">Deactive</option>

                                    </select>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                            <!-- /basic select -->



                            <div class="form-group">

                                <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">

                                    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Edit Package</button>

                                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="reset">Reset</button>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                        </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

In codeingitor, you can get table data in form of JSON like this example

**In model**

```
function function_table_name(){
    $query = $this->db->get('table_name');
     return  $query->result();
}
```

**In Controller**

```
 public function employees()
    {
        $data =  array();
        $data = $this->model_name->function_table_name();

       echo json_encode($data);

        //   echo  '<pre>';
    //  print_r($data);
    }
```

If you want to load this in view you can do like this.

**Controller.php**

```
$data = array();
$data['myJson'] = json_decode(file_get_contents('some_url'));
$this->load->view('my_view',$data);
```

**view.php**

```
<?php 
//Access them like so
print_r($myJson);
// Rest of your code here to play with json 
?>

</html>
```

Comment: By return the $data array in view like you doing already in view for data binding in Codeignitor

Comment: Controller.php

$data = array();
$data['myJson'] = json_decode(file_get_contents('some_url'));
$this->load->view('my_view',$data);
my_view.php

<html>
....
<?php 
//Access them like so
print_r($myJson);
// Rest of your code here to play with json 
?>
....
</html>

Comment: please check the answer, i updated clearly for loading in view

Comment: I must create a .json file?

Comment: No.. no need to create JSON file

Comment: I explain something on my question. I have 2 tables. Package table and packageService table. I write services of package in packageService table. And i want to get this services from packageService table to Package table on column as packageService with json such as "1" "2" etc under packageService column in Package table. How can I adapt this code ?

Comment: Firstly make join between two tables and get data from them and make the same process hopefully that make sense for you . Because you want data from different two table and data in json format right

Comment: Package Table packageService(ID) equal to packageService Table packageServiceId.

Comment: I joined this two tables after that What I will do ?

Comment: Get data from these joined datas and passing from json_encode($results); it's pretty simple, just try this one, it'll be work.

Comment: Just like i’m sending the data to view . Is one way and another way by using Ajax request. Simple is that. But ajax will be complicate for you.

Comment: Yes let me share with you ajax example

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517071/send-json-data-via-post-ajax-and-receive-json-response-from-controller-mvc