# Why does my ajax post to my handler method fail with using POST method, but not when using GET method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Not for the first time, I'm seeing that my Razor Pages seem to be handling GET/POST actions strangely when posting with ajax.

The latest example looks like this:

```
@inject IAntiforgery antiForgery
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Disclaimers";
    Layout = "~/Pages/Shared/_Blade.cshtml";

    var token = antiForgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext).RequestToken;
}

$(".save-button").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;

    const body = document.querySelector(".editor").innerText;
    let disclaimer = {
        clientid: parseInt($("#Disclaimer_Client_Id").val()),
        description: $("#Disclaimer_Description").val(),
        type: $("#Disclaimer_Type").val(),
        markup: body
    };
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "./Create?handler=Create",
        headers: {
            "RequestValidationToken": "@token"
        },
        data: disclaimer,
        dataType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

I've done it this way because I'm using `quilljs` which employs a div for it's rich text editor. I can't use `asp-for` bindings on the div to bind it to the model.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetCreate(CreateDisclaimerViewmodel model)
{
    var disclaimer = new Disclaimer
    {
        Created = DateTime.Now,
        CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name,
        Description = model.Description,
        Markup = model.Markup,
        Type = model.Type
    };
    if (model.ClientId > 0)
    {
        disclaimer.Client = await context.Clients.FindAsync(model.ClientId);
    }

    context.Disclaimers.Add(disclaimer);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Redirect("/Disclaimers/Index");
}
```

With the code set up as using a GET method, it all works, but in this case, it should clearly be a POST.

Change it to a POST however and an empty response is returned with HTTP 400...

```
$(".save-button").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;

    const body = document.querySelector(".editor").innerText;
    let disclaimer = {
        clientid: parseInt($("#Disclaimer_Client_Id").val()),
        description: $("#Disclaimer_Description").val(),
        type: $("#Disclaimer_Type").val(),
        markup: body
    };
    $.ajax({
        // Only the method changes here, everything else is above.
        method: "POST",
        url: "./Create?handler=Create",
        headers: {
            "RequestValidationToken": "@token"
        },
        data: disclaimer,
        dataType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

And the page model:

```
// Only the method changes (OnGetCreate becomes OnPostCreate).
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostCreate(CreateDisclaimerViewmodel model)
{
    var disclaimer = new Disclaimer
    {
        Created = DateTime.Now,
        CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name,
        Description = model.Description,
        Markup = model.Markup,
        Type = model.Type
    };
    if (model.ClientId > 0)
    {
        disclaimer.Client = await context.Clients.FindAsync(model.ClientId);
    }

    context.Disclaimers.Add(disclaimer);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Redirect("/Disclaimers/Index");
}
```

This clearly should be a POST request but it simply won't work when using POST.

So what am I missing or misunderstanding? And since the solution can't be to use GET, what's the solution?

Comment: Is any information provided with that 400 status response?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar nothing whatsoever; log files only show the HTTP 400

Comment: But in the actual response body?

Comment: No response body; dev tools just shows a message: `This request has no response data available.`

Comment: Does it ever hit the method itself?

Comment: Perhaps [this is your problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59955015/3181933)

Comment: Nope; it never hits the method when set as a POST

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar it's not `JSON.stringify`; adding this to the post doesn't change the behavior at all.

Comment: You need be sure you send the correct token for `RequestValidationToken` otherwise it will give you 400 error. How do you get the `@token`?

Comment: @Rena using `IAntiForgery`, I set `var token = antiForgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext).RequestToken;`

Comment: I've never met anyone so insistent on getting feedback. For this particular case, your answer was probably sufficient, however, I had diverted to a different implementation by the time it came so I don't actually know if it would have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

### Shorten answer:

You use the wrong header name, it should be `RequestVerificationToken`:

```
headers: {
     "RequestVerificationToken": "@token"       
},
```

---

You are getting a 400 (Bad Request) response because the framework expects the `RequestVerificationToken` as part of the posted request. Be sure you have send it correctly.

**Common way use ajax post in Razor Pages**

Be sure your form tag does not have `action` attribute and then it will **dynamically add a hidden input for token** (You can F12 in browser to check whether your html contains input named `__RequestVerificationToken`, `Ctrl`+`F` and search for `__RequestVerificationToken`):

```
<form method="post">
     //other elements...  
    <input class="save-button" type="button" value="CHANGE"/>
</form>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
$(".save-button").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault;

    //...
    $.ajax({
        // Only the method changes here, everything else is above.
        method: "POST",
        url: "?handler=Location",
        headers: {
              RequestVerificationToken: $('input:hidden[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val()              
        },
        data: disclaimer,  
        dataType: "application/json",
        //...
    });
});
</script>
}
```

**Otherwise**, you will need **manually** add it by using `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` in the form:

```
<form method="post">
     //other elements... 

      @Html.AntiForgeryToken() 
    <input class="save-button" type="button" value="CHANGE"/>
</form>
```

Comment: using `IAntiForgery`, I set `var token = antiForgery.GetAndStoreTokens(HttpContext).RequestToken;` which is what I'm putting in the javascript. I updated the question with the first code block including the code to get the token

Comment: Hi @psiodrake, If you are sure the token is not null,  your mistake here is use the wrong header name, it should be `RequestVerificationToken`.